# UrlFetchApp function not working with arrays

Tags: google-apps-script, facebook-graph-api, google-sheets, urlencode, urlfetch

I'm using this [IMPORTJSON](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON/blob/master/ImportJSON.gs) script I found on Github to retrieve data from the Facebook Graph API.
It was working fine until I started using filtering arrays in the URL.

For example, this URL works fine :

`https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/account_id/insights?&level=campaign&fields=campaign_name,campaign_id,actions&access_token=access_token&date_preset=last_week_mon_sun`

but when I try to retrieve data from the URL below, I get the following error = **"Exception: Invalid argument"** :

`https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/account_id/insights?&level=campaign&fields=campaign_name,campaign_id,actions&filtering=[{field:"campaign.id",operator:"IN",value:[12345678910]}]&access_token=access_token&date_preset=last_week_mon_sun`

After troubleshooting, I think that the problem comes from the `UrlFetchApp` used in the script.
Is there anyway to format the URL to avoid getting an error ?

Comment: _“For example, this URL works fine”_ - hard to believe, because you are not actually passing any query string parameters there to begin with. This should have been `…/insights?level=…`.

Comment: it's because in the process of removing the access token & the account id I removed extra characters, i've corrected my answer with the proper URLs

Comment: Try to apply proper URL encoding to all parameter values.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: I used the encodeURIcomponent function, and it's working now, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Solution found : I used the encodeURIcomponent function to encode (You have to use it on the parameters only, not on the whole URL !)
Eg : encodeURIComponent([{field:"campaign.id",operator:"IN",value:[12345678910]}])